# The sand buggy has one wheel stuck in the ground and I can't continue

Tags: xbox-360, half-life-2

I'm playing Half Life 2 on The Orange Box for the Xbox 360. I'm in the "Highway 17" section, and at some point while driving along the sand, my buggy got one of it's wheels "stuck" in the ground. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

It got stuck somewhere shortly before the base where you have to shoot down the airship with the rpg. I literally used the gravity gun to push it along to that base. Now I can't get it from the soft ground onto the road to continue. Here's another screenshot:

[image]

When I try to push it onto the road, it does all kinds of flips and craziness, but that wheel never comes out of the ground.

None of my save files go back far enough before this bug happened (I feel stupid). What do I do?

#### Edit

I just tried walking back all the way to where I originally got the buggy, and that didn't help. I didn't really think it would, but it was worth a try.

### Edit

I started a new game, starting at the beginning of that "Highway 17" Chapter, and for a while, things were good. But once I got to the area right before the airship base (there's a Combine controlled house, where the three guys are outside at first and are easily dealt with with the buggy gun, and a rowboat hanging from the ceiling inside), where if I went into certain spongier parts of the beach it happened again.

Comment: Ah, I sure to love the crazy glitches that make up Half Life 2. A console command might work (not sure which one). If you cannot proceed without it, then you might have to restart.

Comment: In your second screenshot, the road seem to rise. Try to push your buggy there, then push it off the road. With a little bit of luck, the wheel should get stuck at the edge of the road, so the buggy is suspended in mid-air through the wheel. From there, just use the grav gun to "force" the wheel off the ground by repeatedly pushing the buggy off the road. Hopefully, the force should (eventually) dislodge the wheel from the ground. If not, you'll have to restart the chapter, unfortunately. You'll need the buggy to jump off bridges, after all.

Comment: @Thebluefish. I'm sure you can't use console commands in the Xbox 360 version.

Comment: @Nolonar If I remember right, I seem to recall that modifying config files allow you to keybind console commands. It's been forever since I've done game save modification though.

Comment: Yeah everyone, make sure to remember that this is for the xbox 360 version. If I do any config file editing or console commands, you'll have to provide some sort of explanation of how to do that.

Comment: Crouching down really close to the buggy, and and using the grav gun to shoot **up** at it might pull it out the ground.

Answer (score 2):

Start a new game, beginning at Chapter 7. You're started with all the same guns, and everything will be fine.

Just be sure to watch out in the area right before the airship base. There's a Combine controlled house, where the three guys are outside at first and are easily dealt with with the buggy gun, and a rowboat hanging from the ceiling inside. After that house, go as quickly and directly to the next base as possible, avoiding the softer sand. That's where it consistently happened to me.